# how to display decimals

Tags: javascript

I've tried numerous examples but need to know how to code it

I have the following code which is within a form:

```
   document.getElementById("65_element10").value=parseInt(document.getElementById("63_element10").value)+parseInt(document.getElementById("64_element10").value);
```

and need to have the result displayed as 99.99  but how do i change the code, i think i need to use some thing like this:

```
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
double price = 2.50000000000003;
System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(price));
```

Comment: The first piece is JavaScript. JS != Java!

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

If you only want two decimal digits then use it like this:

```
var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("63_element10").value);
var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("64_element10").value);
var sum = a+b;
document.getElementById("65_element10").value = parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2);
```

Be aware that JavaScript is not Java. You can not mix it!

Comment: Also the Java code returns `$2.50`. Not sure how JavaScript handles the dollar sign

Comment: It will have problems with the dollar sign. You have to remove it manually.